# Trigger failing to create manual sharing for account

Tags: apex, trigger, manual-sharing

**Scenario**

I have Community users that I need to share some account records to, where the Account that the Community user is linked to is referenced by a lookup field on the Account record to share.

I have set the OWD for external users on Account to Private, with it set to Read/Write for internal users. I have enabled manual sharing and created a trigger on Account which should create a sharing rule on insert or update of the account record, however when I have been testing by manually editing account records it is not creating a record in the AccountShare, but I get no error messages in the log.

It is throwing an error when I try and do the database create

> 09:52:04:031 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [48]|result|[{"success":false,"errors":[{"status":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSI (2 more) ...","message":"missing required fie (28 more) ..."}]}]|0x12272438

**Trigger Code**

```
    trigger WSC_Account_Trigger on Account (before insert, after insert, after update) {

    /*
     * Account trigger - mainly required for security settings for customer premises
     */

    If(Trigger.isAfter&&trigger.isInsert){
        WSC_Account_Trigger_Handler.accountShare(Trigger.New);
        //call helper class to set Apex account sharing
    }

    If(trigger.isAfter&&Trigger.isUpdate){
        WSC_Account_Trigger_Handler.accountShare(Trigger.New);
       //call helper class to set Apex account sharing 

    }

}
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
    public class WSC_Account_Trigger_Handler {
    /*
     * Account Trigger handler 
     * Main purpose to use Apex Sharing for Customer accounts to the relevant retailers using the 
     * 
     */

    Public static void accountShare(List<Account> shareAccounts){

        List<AccountShare> toShareAccount = new List<AccountShare>();
        AccountShare shAccounts = new AccountShare();
        for(Account newAcc : shareAccounts){
            //Water retailer shares
            system.Debug('premises name '+newAcc.Name);
            if(newAcc.Retailer__c !=Null){
                Id waterRetailerId = newAcc.Retailer__c;
                Id PremisesId = newAcc.Id;
                List<User> accUsers = new List<User>();
                accUsers = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE User.AccountId = :waterRetailerId];
                System.debug('accUsers '+ accUsers.size());
                for(User shareUser : accUsers){
                     System.debug('Premises name '+ newAcc.Name+' '+PremisesId);
                     shAccounts.AccountId = PremisesId;
                     shAccounts.UserOrGroupId = shareUser.Id;
                     shAccounts.AccountAccessLevel = 'Read';
                     toShareAccount.add(shAccounts);
                }
            }
        } //end water retailer shares

        for(Account newAcc : shareAccounts){
            //Sewerage retailer shares
            if(newAcc.Sewerage_Retailer__c !=Null&&newAcc.Retailer__c!=newAcc.Sewerage_Retailer__c){
                Id sewerageRetailerId = newAcc.Sewerage_Retailer__c;
                List<User> accUsers = new List<User>();
                accUsers = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE User.AccountId = :sewerageRetailerId];
                System.debug('accUsers '+ accUsers.size());
                for(User shareUser : accUsers){
                     shAccounts.AccountId = newAcc.Id;
                     shAccounts.UserOrGroupId = shareUser.Id;
                     shAccounts.AccountAccessLevel = 'Read';
                     toShareAccount.add(shAccounts);
                }
            }
        } //end sewerage retailer shares
        System.debug('No of shares to create'+toShareAccount.size());
        System.assert(toShareAccount.size()>0);
        Database.SaveResult[] result = Database.insert(toShareAccount, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: It says required fields are missing, check if all the fields are being populated as expected for insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing setting `OpportunityAccessLevel` attribute while preparing AccountShare records to insert. `OpportunityAccessLevel` is required to insert AccountShare record.
So Below correction can help you:

```
   for(User shareUser : accUsers){
        System.debug('Premises name '+ newAcc.Name+' '+PremisesId);
        shAccounts.AccountId = PremisesId;
        shAccounts.UserOrGroupId = shareUser.Id;
        shAccounts.AccountAccessLevel = 'Read';
        shAccounts.OpportunityAccessLevel='Read';
        toShareAccount.add(shAccounts);
        }
```

Comment: I have actually added all the other sharing, which in my scenario is OpportunityAccessLevel='None', CaseAccessLevel ='Read',ContactAccessLevel='None'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing  **OpportunityAccessLevel** 
   please refer following for more details. 
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountshare.htm

```
     for(Account objAccount: accountList){
        AccountShare objAccountShare = new AccountShare ();
        objAccountShare.AccountId = objAccount.Id;
        objAccountShare.UserOrGroupID  = 'PutuserOrGroupId';
        objAccountShare.AccountAccessLevel  = 'read';
        objAccountShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'read';
        accountSharesInsertList.add(objAccountShare);
    }//for
```

Thanks.
Nachiket